# Prevent foot cramp from standing at workspace

Tags: pain, musculoskeletal-system, feet

I've made myself a standing workspace (because of getting strain injuries from sitting).

Everything was going well until I started getting cramps in my feet.  I first noticed this while swimming.

It looks as though the tendon running along the sole of the foot is being constantly stretched.

Can anyone think of a good solution?

I'm thinking of something like the mats they use at Dojos, something that the foot would sink into enough that it is supported everywhere, but I can't find any product that fits my needs.

Comment: Just a clarification - Tendons connect muscle to bone, and as such don't really cramp. Are you getting foot cramps in the muscles actually in the sole of the foot, or are you getting tendon pain?

Comment: @JohnP, not sure if I can tell, but I believe it is in the muscles in the sole.  The third and fourth toes sometimes seem to be trying to cross over one another.  Although I guess that may only make sense to someone that has experienced the same.

Comment: No, it makes sense. I used to swim competitively and got the same thing. Unfortunately, cramps are a mystery still. You may have to just work up to the standing, and make sure that you have good ergonomic shoes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that shoes with good bridge support may be the answer here.

I've been working wearing slippers (one of the many dangers of working at home!).

My guess is that whatever tendon runs the length of the sole was getting put under constant stress.

I've now taken a fortnight away from standing, and I'm using my tennis trainers upon return.

I think a better solution would be if I could find some mat made out of some kind of spongy material that allows the entire foot to sink into it, maybe at a slight angle so the heels are at a higher level than the toes, as I would guess the heel will sink further.

However, I won't accept this (or any other) answer until I am certain my feet are back to a healthy state.

EDIT: June 2016, A HogHeaven anti-fatigue mat has done the job perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Anti-fatigue mats will distribute pressure more evenly.

Vitamins A, B6 and B9, as well as copper and iron help produce blood, which, if lacking, can lead to cramps.

Drink water! I read it helps cramps as well.

Stay cool? Don't quote me on that.

Do a warm-up before swimming, then after a cool-down.

Jump around when you wake up. It prevents muscles from tying up.

Stay flex. Stretch often.

And last (and maybe the least) drink pickle juice. And a Gatorade (electrolytes).

Comment: Hello and welcome. You seem to have some valuable information to contribute, but, [your post needs references to reliable sources](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1/165) in order to be considered a good answer on this site. (Please flag for removal of post notice if you’re willing to [edit] accordingly.)

Comment: Despite 2 downvotes, a "HogHeaven" antifatigue mat has solved the problem. 6 months and going good! It's a good answer, upvote it!

Comment: @Pi No, it's a poor answer that happened to contain (common) advice that worked for you.

Comment: My references would be most of the first results in a Google search "how to prevent cramps." Common is an understatement.